# Should I build typescript in my CI pipeline if I use eslint with typescript plugin

Tags: typescript, eslint, cicd

I'm configuring Github actions for my typescript project (nothing special yet, just Node.js). I use eslint with typescript plugin first on the code base. Then prettier. I've seen many times that build step is used as well (like `tsx build`). However, is it necessary, I already run eslint-typescript (with `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking`)? Does this plugin build the project and do I have to separately run the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll still need to build.

ESLint is a linter, not a build tool. It simply checks your codes for specific issues. You can see the issues it checks with the plugin you mentioned here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended-requiring-type-checking.ts

There are additional problems that can only be encountered with a proper build action. ESLint can't catch everything, sadly :)

For instance, if you upgrade a dependency that suddenly causes CSS to stop compiling, you'd only learn about that through a build step.